# Steam trade without steam mobile authenticator

Tags: steam

I have a steam account that is unlimited(I've paid 5 dollars) and have an email authenticator on.
my question is if I make a trade now does this trade get delayed or not(immediately)?
I turned mobile authenticator 3 months ago, but disabled it last month, so if I can't make a trade immediately with email authenticator, and turn mobile one again, does it get a penalty(15 days) or not?(cause some say that only first time has penalty)
Actually, I wanna make a trade as fast as I can so I'll be pleased if you have good suggestions.

Comment: What is an unlimited steam account? Do you mean, you verified your email adres?
Have you simply tried making a trade? If so, what message do you get?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid It means you've paid at least $5 on the account. Accounts that have paid $0 have limits on what they can trade as an anti-fraud measure.